# How to change css of asterick generated by required in angular material form field?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material-6

I am using angular material in angular6 app.

```
        <mat-form-field fxFlex>
            <mat-label [class.form-label]="fg.get('email').valid && fg.get('email').touched">{{attributesLabels.email}}</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="email" required [autofocus]="true">
            <mat-error *ngIf="fg.get('email').hasError('required')">Email is required</mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="fg.get('email').hasError('email') && !fg.get('email').hasError('required') ">Invalid email</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
```

This is required field and in the placeholder of this input field, "*" is append after placeholder like below: 
[image]

I want to change the color of "*" in the placeholder to red. How can i change the color?

Html Generated by the above mat-form-field:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This super simple thing for me was at the root of the project in styles.scss just put

```
.mat-form-field-required-marker { color: red }
```

Comment: I would add that use of /deep/ or ::ng-deep is deprecated and use therein is discouraged.

Answer (score 5):

Just try this,In html part

```
 <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid" appearance="outline">
    <mat-label class="asterisk_input" >First Name</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="email" />
</mat-form-field>
```

and add the following code in the component .css file

```
.asterisk_input::after 
{
    content:" *"; 
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: The input needs to be required.  Adding `required` will add a second, uncolored asterisk

Answer (score 4):

Add the following code in your css file:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-required-marker { color: red }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an input on matFormField you can use `hideRequiredMarker` as you can see here https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api

```
   <mat-form-field fxFlex hideRequiredMarker="true">
        <mat-label [class.form-label]="fg.get('email').valid && fg.get('email').touched">{{attributesLabels.email}}</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="email" required [autofocus]="true">
        <mat-error *ngIf="fg.get('email').hasError('required')">Email is required</mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="fg.get('email').hasError('email') && !fg.get('email').hasError('required') ">Invalid email</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Then maybe you can try to do your own stuff with pseudoClasses in CSS :after

Answer (score 1):

[ckIkram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6364050/ckram)'s suggestion was good but i figured out another solution.

Angular Material treat place holder as a label, so i wrote this css to change the color of asterick *.

```
/deep/ label span.mat-form-field-required-marker{
   color:red;
}
```

This is what's worked for me but a word of caution, the /deep/ selector is depreciated so eventually this wont work in future...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately even the [styling of the placeholder text](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/) is pretty experimental, and I tried adding the `:after` pseudo-selector to get the red star, but it didn't work.

The below is the nearest I could get to what you wanted.

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #ccc;
}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #ccc;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: #ccc;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #ccc;
}
  
label:after {
  content: " *";
  color: #ff0000;
  }
```

```html
<label>Email</label>
<br/>
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="required">
```

Alternatively, you could make the entire placeholder text red, and include a star in it.